# Get manager of current user in workflow

Tags: workflow, spuser

how can I get the current user's manager's phone information.

I select the current user id like this:

```
public Guid workflowId = default(System.Guid);
public SPWorkflowActivationProperties workflowProperties = new SPWorkflowActivationProperties();

    private void onWorkflowActivated1_Invoked(object sender, ExternalDataEventArgs e)
    {

        SPWeb web = workflowProperties.Web;

        SPUser spuser = this.workflowProperties.OriginatorUser;

        string strusername = spuser.Name;
        string strid = spuser.LoginName;

        SPListItem lisitem= workflowProperties.Item;

        if (lisitem["Full Name"] == null)
        {
            listitem["Full Name"] = strid;
            listitem.Update();
        }
```

but i couldnt find a way to reach manager 's phone information.